# Capitalizing the word "media"

Tags: capitalization

When referring to the overall news media, can I use the capitalized word "Media"?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Try to be more specific about your intended usage. Is this specifically just the news media, not general TV or other aspects of media? Example sentences are useful in cases like this for people to easily follow what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you would still use media. You'd only capitalise if you were referring to the place or to a particular proper noun i.e. "this year I'm going to college to study Media Studies".

Answer (score 2):

I would go with media and not Media.
We must understand that unnecessary capitalization is futile.

Answer (score 0):

Overall news media is media.
Single media sources are actually called mediums.

It's from Latin. Singular - Medium. Plural - Media.
Depends on the context, but i'm guessing overall is everything overall. In that case, why not?

Actually, why would you do that? It's one thing to emphasize with Capitalizing, but a properly structured and worded sentence can go miles further than any attempt at poor emphasis indication.

I'd rather you not, but you can. Valid, but not... nice?